# Raising the dead (notebooks)

Tags: front-end, crash

I have a notebook which has a lot of generated data (which I would rather not regenerate), and the kernel is dead. So, the question is, how do I recover the data in the notebook (I know it is there, since the save file is very, very large, but obbiously `%28`, or whatever, will not work). I can copy the output cell as LaTeX or MathML [which is not what I want] or convert it to InputForm (which IS what I want, but where does the converted thing go then?)

Anyway, this is a newbie sort of question, but, well...

Comment: If in output there is somethin you would not evaluate, do not use this. But if there are only simple output cells, try: `With[{l = Length[#]},   CreateDocument@    Table[
     With[{var = "x" <> ToString[i]},      Composition[     Cell[#, "Input"] &, BoxData, Cases[#, BoxData[x_] :> RowBox[{var, "=", x, ";"}], 1][[1]] &,NotebookRead ]@#[[i]]
      ], {i, l}] ] &[Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Output"] ]`

Answer (score 5):

So is the scenario that you have some notebook with input cells that look like

```
data = myfunctionThatGivesALotOfData[...]
```

which have produced output cells that look like

```
{9.34648, ... ,7.6569}
```

and you want to start a new kernel session and get the value of `data` ?

If that's the case, you can just put your cursor at the beginning of the output cell(in this case `{9.34648, ...`) and then just type `data =` and it will automagically convert the output cell into an input cell, and once you evaluate it you'll have your definition of `data`.

If you want to do this programmatically via something like `NotebookGet` then that's a bit more involved, but not terrible(I'd suggest starting on the ref page for `NotebookGet`).

Comment: Truly, you are wise in the ways of science!

Comment: Except when I did this (this is in MMA 10.0.1, in case it matters, and then I asked for the value of "data", I got %29. Now, maybe I should reload the notebook, and see what happens?!

Comment: Or, to make it clearer: if my cursor is inside the "grey" area (where the output is), mathematica does not accept input. If I put it just outside, I get `%28` (for whatever reason) as the value.

Comment: @IgorRivin if the info is stored in one of those gray, large-output boxes, it is properly gone. That's just an input form for `%n`. To demonstrate this, try: `ConstantArray[10000, {1000, 1000}]` followed by `ToExpression[First@NotebookRead@NextCell[], StandardForm, HoldForm]` in the same cell (so that `NextCell` catches the output from the `ConstantArray` call). Sorry to disappoint.